# How can I prevent colliding Cloth Objects from wrinkling each other?

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, modifiers, collision, force-fields

I am trying to create a model of paper being blown by wind using a model with a Cloth Modifier and a Force Field of wind.
However, when I play them in animation, the Cloth objects that collide with each other end up crumpled, curled and became like a ball.
What should I change?

I'll share some screenshots of my current setup:
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Update 1**(something is still wrong) 
-Added Self Collisions.(Distance 0.015)
-Added Solidify Modifier.(Thickness 0.01m)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you have self collisions turned off. so do you mean they collider with each other or with themselves? I think you should avoid 2d simulations by adding depth (e.g. solidify modifier) might resolve it.

Comment: It wasn't my purpose making them collider with each other nor themselves. It's just by my lack of knowledge. Thanks for telling me that.
I've try added solidify modifier to them after your advice. But in the simulation, they now became different shape, like crushed ice cube on it's edge. Is there any rule and relation between the Thickness of Cloth Objects and the Distance of Object Collision? (I added screen shot of my settings.)

Comment: For example, one of the numbers should be set larger than the other, or they should be the same, etc.?

Comment: uses softbody physic but might be helpful: https://youtu.be/F8j1K-_OlH4 and https://youtu.be/U1f6NDCttUY (texturing)

Comment: I've tried Softbody physic before, and the result looked too soft. (Hope I can do better one day...) 
I'd like to try with Cloth this time. The YouTube Channel you recommended is fun and motivating. I'll check out the others as well. Thank you very much.

Comment: adding your blend file would help a lot because then we can try it out ourselves instead of guessing what might be the reason...